# VPN app/VPN macbook 2003 10.6.8

Tags: macbook-pro, vpn, macos

i have a 2003 10.6.8 and i  am not able to install vpn app as it prompt me that my macbook need to have 62 bit intel processor, can someone please advice or recommend an vpn app for my macbook please ?

Comment: Is it 200 MacBook? If you cannot install the VPN app, then just use the username and password from the provider with the OS X inbuilt VPN utility.

Comment: Please add more details (see Steve's answer below for what is missing) so the answers can be tailored more specifically to your setup.

Answer (score 1):

You do not say **which** 2003 model of Mac you have but 2003 Macs do not have Intel processors and your version of macOS (normally referred to as Snow Leopard) is *old* and likely unsupported by most current applications both for the OS version and the PowerPC chip in your Mac.

macOS does have a built-in VPN (I believe with Snow Leopard as well...). PPTP is fairly common (especially if it is a Cisco or Cisco-compatible VPN) and you might be able to configure it to work with your VPN service, but I would not count on it, especially if it is a commercial VPN service, as they often use their own APP to connect to their VPN service.

You are possibly out of luck, unless someone here knows specifically one that works with your configuration.

If you indicate what you are trying to accomplish or even which ones you wanted to try that might help us help you.